# How to compact large directories

Tags: ext3, directory

Is there a way to compact a very large directory under EXT2/EXT3 without simply remaking the directory?

I recall that [*perlfunc*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) cautions that the OS implementations of `seekdir` and `telldir` run the risk of directory compaction. which sounds like what I want in this case, but I'm unfamiliar with those semantics in practice.

**background:**
I've a few directories that are themselves many MB in size -- they were overrun with a zillion small files in the past:

```
$ ls -lh
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 1.3M Oct  5 12:49 big
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 2.3M Oct  5 12:49 this_one_is_empty_now
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 6.1M Oct  5 12:49 yikes
```

Comment: Reiser3 is the answer. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Directories can not be compacted online exactly *because* of the requirements of seekdir/telldir.  They require any program to be able to maintain position within the directory for indefinite time and still only read any given entry once; therefore, the entries can not be moved around while the fs is mounted.

You can compact the directory offline with `e2fsck -D`.

Comment: I think those are rather soft requirements, as the GNU docs for `dirent` caution that seekdir/telldir may not be reliable.  The point about e2fsck is well taken. +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/)?  It's an improved gzip.

John Allspaw talks about it on his blog here:
http://www.kitchensoap.com/2010/04/02/pigz-parallel-gzip-omg/

Comment: I think the OP wants to reduce the size of the directory file within the filesystem rather than compress the actual files